# strcpy and strcat cause problems sometimes

Tags: strcpy, strcat

hello I have a code like the one below

```
char *str ;

        strcpy(str, "\t<");
        strcat(str, time);
        strcat(str, ">[");
        strcat(str, user);
        strcat(str, "]");
        strcat(str, "(");
        strcat(str, baseName);
        strcat(str, ") $ ");

        printf("\String is now: %s\n", str);
```

This code seems working but when I use XCode analyse function, it says "Function call argument is an uninitialized value" and also it sometimes causes my program crash.. when I remove it, then it works fine...  Whats wrong with that? Thanks

Comment: have you allocated memory for str?

Comment: @kanoz: It's important because you can't write into anything except legally allocated memory.

Comment: For future reference, str is commonly known as a **dangling** or **wild** pointer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strcpy` and `strcat` are used to copy and concatenate strings to an allocated char array.

Since `str` in not initilized you're writing somewhere in memory and this is bad because you're corrupting other data. It may work at that moment but sooner or later you'll program will crash.

You should allocate memory when declaring str:

`char str[100];`

Also, `strcat` is not efficient as it needs to search for the string end to know where concatenate chars. Using `sprintf` would be more efficient:

`sprintf(str, "\t<%s>[%s](%s) $ ", time, user, baseName);`

Finally, if you can't guarantee the generated string will fit the array, you'd better use snsprintf.

Answer (score 2):

You don't allocate memory and you leave `str` uninitialized. All later writes are done through an uninitialized pointer that points "somewhere" - that's undefined behavior.

You have to allocate (and later free) memory large enough to hold the resulting string:

```
char *str = malloc( computeResultSizeSomehow() );
if( str == 0 ) {
   // malloc failed - handle as fatal error
}

//proceed with your code, then

free( str );
```

Comment: what is computeResultSizeSomehow()?

Comment: Try reading something about pointers before trying to use them. http://boredzo.org/pointers/

Comment: @kanoz: You have to evaluate how much memory you need. That's called pseudocode.

Answer (score 2):

This is *much* simpler and error-free from buffer overflows:

```
#define BUFFERSIZE 512
char str[BUFFERSIZE];

snprintf(str, BUFFERSIZE, "\t<%s>[%s](%s) $ ", time, user, baseName);
```

Comment: sprintf "prints" in a string, not in your monitor.

Comment: @wormsparty You mean the fixed-size array? Or the snprintf? Cause the first only constraints you.

Comment: If you need it somewhere else, for example by returning it from the function: `return strdup(str)`, and free it later.

Comment: sprintf prints in an array of characters in your "storage", not to your stdout(1)->output screen