# Concatenate two char* strings in a C program

Tags: c

I wrote the following C program:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    char* str1;
    char* str2;
    str1 = "sssss";
    str2 = "kkkk";
    printf("%s", strcat(str1, str2));

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
 }
```

I want to concatenate the two strings, but it doesn't work.

Comment: You are failing to allocate a destination buffer of sufficient size, and attempting to write to non-modifiable memory.

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work?", what do you mean? What is it printing instead of what it's supposed to? Even if it's fairly obvious, you should also say what you think it's supposed to print, to make it clear.

Comment: see this question [Using strcat in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419604/using-strcat-in-c)

Comment: possible duplicate of [strcpy and strcat cause problems sometimes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254648/strcpy-and-strcat-cause-problems-sometimes)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The way it works is to:

1. Malloc memory large enough to hold copies of str1 and str2
2. Then it copies str1 into str3
3. Then it appends str2 onto the end of str3
4. When you're using str3 you'd normally free it `free (str3);`

Here's an example for you play with. It's very simple and has no hard-coded lengths. You can try it here: http://ideone.com/d3g1xs

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215445/are-there-machines-where-sizeofchar-1) for information about size of char

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

      char* str1;
      char* str2;
      str1 = "sssss";
      str2 = "kkkk";
      char * str3 = (char *) malloc(1 + strlen(str1)+ strlen(str2) );
      strcpy(str3, str1);
      strcat(str3, str2);
      printf("%s", str3);

      return 0;
 }
```

Comment: what's the difference of `str3 = "sssss"` and `strcpy(str3,str1)`?

Comment: str3 needs to point at memory that's large enough to hold the string. That's why I malloced it in the line above.

Comment: But after this code `char * str3 = (char *) malloc(1 +sizeof(char*) * (strlen(str1)+ strlen(str2)));` Why not use `str3 = "sssss"` but use `strcpy(str3,str1)` instead?:)

Comment: Because we don't want to point str3 at str1. It's a constant. There's no room to copy characters onto the end of it.

Comment: But you have malloced a memory,isn't it?

Comment: I malloced enough memory for copies of str2, str3, +1 more (for the string null termination character.

Comment: Multiplying by `sizeof(char)` is pointless (and not advised).

Comment: @NikBougalis what do you mean?can you explain more detail? thanks :)

Comment: @BeCurious in C and C++ the result of `sizeof(char)` is always *guaranteed* to be 1. So multiplying by it is pointless.

Comment: I also added a link to what sizeof char meant.

Comment: @dcaswell In this line `char * str3 = (char *) malloc(1 + strlen(str1)+ strlen(str2) );` . Do you need the `(char *) `? `malloc` confuses me when you get fancy.

Comment: I get instant crash, why ?

Comment: Isn't there a word missing in the step 4?

Answer (score 22):

[Here](http://ideone.com/RPuOAK) is a working solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
      char str1[16];
      char str2[16];
      strcpy(str1, "sssss");
      strcpy(str2, "kkkk");
      strcat(str1, str2);
      printf("%s", str1);
      return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
ssssskkkk
```

You have to allocate memory for your strings. In the above code, I declare `str1` and `str2` as character arrays containing 16 characters. I used `strcpy` to copy characters of string literals into them, and `strcat` to append the characters of `str2` to the end of `str1`. Here is how these character arrays look like during the execution of the program:

```
After declaration (both are empty): 
str1: [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][] 
str2: [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]

After calling strcpy (\0 is the string terminator zero byte): 
str1: [s][s][s][s][s][\0][][][][][][][][][][][][][][] 
str2: [k][k][k][k][\0][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]

After calling strcat: 
str1: [s][s][s][s][s][k][k][k][k][\0][][][][][][][][][][] 
str2: [k][k][k][k][\0][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
```

Answer (score 3):

`strcat`  concats `str2` onto `str1`

You'll get runtime errors because `str1` is  not being properly allocated for concatenation

Comment: In fact `strcat` does return the concatenated string.

Answer (score 2):

When you use string literals, such as `"this is a string"` and in your case `"sssss"` and `"kkkk"`, the compiler puts them in read-only memory. However, `strcat` attempts to write the second argument after the first. You can solve this problem by making a sufficiently sized destination buffer and write to that.

```
char destination[10]; // 5 times s, 4 times k, one zero-terminator
char* str1;
char* str2;
str1 = "sssss";
str2 = "kkkk";
strcpy(destination, str1);
printf("%s",strcat(destination,str2));
```

Note that in recent compilers, you usually get a warning for casting string literals to non-const character pointers.

Answer (score 1):

`strcat(str1, str2)` appends str2 after str1. It requires str1 to have enough space to hold str2. In you code, str1 and str2 are all string constants, so it should not work. You may try this way:

```
char str1[1024];
char *str2 = "kkkk";
strcpy(str1, "ssssss");
strcat(str1, str2);
printf("%s", str1);
```

Answer (score 1):

`strcat` attempts to append the second parameter to the first. This won't work since you are assigning implicitly sized constant strings.

If all you want to do is print two strings out

```
printf("%s%s",str1,str2);
```

Would do.

You could do something like

```
char *str1 = calloc(sizeof("SSSS")+sizeof("KKKK")+1,sizeof *str1);
strcpy(str1,"SSSS");
strcat(str1,str2);
```

to create a concatenated string; however strongly consider using strncat/strncpy instead. And read the man pages carefully for the above. (oh and don't forget to `free` str1 at the end).

Comment: What's the difference of `str1="ssss"` and `strcpy(str1,"ssss")`?