# How can I intuitively insert a string for a shader uniform in C?

Tags: c

This code would have worked in C++, but it's giving me an error in C:

```
setvVec3("objs[" + oo + "].color", obj.color);
```

and the error:

"invalid operands to binary + (have ‘char *’ and ‘char *’)"

Comment: In C++, you can concatenate strings using the + operator. In C, you can use the strcat function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18468387/600135

Comment: Or use `sprintf` to create the string.

Comment: Example code for sprintf: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/?kw=sprintf

Answer (score 1):

As @kol pointed out, you cannot concatenate strings in C with the + operator: You can however use the function `strcat`. If you want to use `strcat` to concatenate the three strings, your code will need to look more like this:

```
/* assuming oo is a char* */
char str[100] = "objs[";
     
setvVec3(strcat(strcat(str, oo), "].color"), obj.color);
```

Please note that I chose the array size at random, but keep in mind that the size of the destination character array will need to be large enough to hold the concatenated string, otherwise you will likely spill into unwanted memory.

To find more information about the C function `strcat`, check out this link:
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcat.3.html

**EDIT:** Since you say that `oo` is an integer, you will need to additionally convert it to a character array using the function `snprintf`, like so:

```
/* assuming oo is a not char*, but rather an int */
char str[100] = "objs[";

char ootochar[10];
snprintf(ootochar, 10, "%d", oo);

setvVec3(strcat(strcat(str, ootochar), "].color"), obj.color);
```

Comment: oo is an int... what do I do now?

Comment: @DiamondyguyJacobs: Use [`snprintf`](https://man7.org/linux/manpages/man3/snprintf.3p.html). Or [`asprintf`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html) if you don't care about Windows, or have an implementation handy. Also, I don't think it would work with an `int oo` on C++, either.

Comment: Try and link to a canonical reference, not some "tutorials" site.

Answer (score 1):

The conventional way is to use [`sprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) to use formatted buffers, like this:

```c
int bsize = 100;
char buffer[bsize];

snprintf(buffer, bsize "objs[%s].color", obj.color);
```

So long as `obj.color` isn't egregiously long this will work. Technically you should pay attention to the return code to ensure it was successful.

Note the use of `snprintf` here, which is the safe version of `sprintf`. The old `sprintf` function will overflow your buffer without warning and can cause serious bugs in programs. `snprintf` is the same but with that limit argument.